# void * to struct * in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void-pointers

I have a basic typecasting question... I have a struct

```
typedef struct teststruct {
  int a;
} test;
```

And a simple function

```
void testfunc(void **s)
{
  printf("trying malloc\n");
  s[0] = (test*)s[0];
  s[0] = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test));
  s[0]->a = 2;
}
```

However when I compile, I get

```
test.c:21:7: error: member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union
  s[0]->a = 2;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks much for all your help :)
Vik.

Comment: Why is the parameter `void**` and not `test**`?

Comment: I need to call the method from nodejs's foreign function interface in javascript. It understands void and not custom defined structures.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: @Nabla has the answer; but what do you intend to accomplish with `s[0] = (test*)s[0];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is meaningless:

```
 s[0] = (test*)s[0];
```

As it assigns `s[0]` to itself.

I suspect that you *think* it changes the type of `s[0]` from a `void*` to a `test*`.
But that is not accurate.

Type-casts only affect how a variable is interpreted immediately, at the point of the type-cast.
It does not change the type of the variable in any lasting sense.

As a result, when your program reaches this line:

```
s[0]->a = 2;
```

`s[0]` is still a `void*`, and so de-referencing it for variable `a` is not valid.

What you really want is:

```
((test*)s[0])->a = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you can not change the type of a variable wuthin your scope. You have to define a new one with the new type.

```
void testfunc(void **s)
{
  printf("trying malloc\n");
  test * s_test_type = s[0]; // no need to cast to/from void *
  s_test_type = (test*)s[0];
  s_test_type = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test));
  s_test_type->a = 2;
}
```